# Flutter: Not able to select items in Radio button, in ListTile

Tags: flutter, dart

Im a newbie, Not able to select items in Radio button, inside a  ListTile. I tied to use same code without ListTile and working as expected. Looks like combination is not correct or i might be missing something.

```
class _TempState extends State<Temp> {
  int selectedValue = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
            child: Container(
                child: Column(children: [
          Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                  child: Text("Radio button with ListView",))],),
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: 1,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return OrderItem();
                }),),
        ]))));}

  Widget OrderItem() {
    int selectedValue = 0;
    return ListTile(
        title: Container(
            child: Column(children: [
      Row(
        children: [
          Expanded(
              child: Text(
            "Product Type :",
          )),
          Radio<int>(
            value: 1,
            groupValue: selectedValue,
            onChanged: (value) {
              setState(() {
                selectedValue = value != null ? value.toInt() : 1;
              });
            },
          ),
          Text('NRML'),
          Radio<int>(
              value: 2,
              groupValue: selectedValue,
              onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  selectedValue = value != null ? value.toInt() : 1;
                });
              }),
          Text('MARKET'),
        ],), ])));
  }}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are updating your `selectedValue` in wrong way ,first define your `selectedValue` like this:

```
int? selectedValue;
```

then update your widget like this:

```
Widget OrderItem() {//remove int selectedValue = 0; here
    return ListTile(
      title: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                    child: Text(
                  "Product Type :",
                )),
                Radio<int>(
                  value: 1,
                  groupValue: selectedValue,
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    setState(() {
                      selectedValue = value; //<-- change this
                    });
                  },
                ),
                Text('NRML'),
                Radio<int>(
                    value: 2,
                    groupValue: selectedValue,
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      setState(() {
                        selectedValue = value; //<-- change this
                      });
                    }),
                Text('MARKET'),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Also another reason that is not working is that you are define another `int selectedValue = 0;` in your OrderItem method, you need to remove it.

[image]

Comment: Used same code but no luck, Still not able to select radio button.

Comment: @user3397828 I updated my answer, you need to remove `int selectedValue = 0;` in `OrderItem`.

Answer (score 0):

In your second radio you should change your `setState` to

```
selectedValue = value != null ? value.toInt() : 2;
```

Value you assign to radio will be used to determine which radio is selected. So if you want to select second radio you should assign its value when selecting

Comment: Tried updating selectedValue, but no luck, Still not able to select radio button.

Answer (score 0):

```
selectedValue = value != null ? value.toInt() : 2;
```

`Value` you assign to radio will be used to determine which radio is selected. So if you want to select second radio you should assign its `value` when selecting

Comment: Tried updating selectedValue, but no luck, Still not able to select radio button.